# calculate sum and median by importying csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, sum, mean

```
public class data {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        String fileName = "Book1.csv";// File name is book1.csv
        File file = new File(fileName); // read file
        try{
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext()){  // ignore first line
                String data = inputStream.next();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            inputStream.close();

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}
```

output

[image]

I want to calculate the sum of the values of followers. can you please help me

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: the actual question is to calculate the sum for the value of followers columns. @QBrute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split String and transform to double. Like this:

```
double sum = 0;
while (inputStream.hasNext()){  // ignore first line
               String data = inputStream.next();
               
               double value = Double.valueOf(data.split(",")[1]); //[1] - number after ','
               sum+= value;    
            }
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: thanks. I did in the same way too. Also, can u help in calculating the mode and range for the values@Oleg